# linq-to-sql update conditionally

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a query to update a record; it looks somewhat like this:

```
public void SaveRecord(int TheUserID, Nullable<DateTime> TheDate,
                                                  Nullable<int> TheAction)
    {
      using DC...
      {
         var TheRecordToUpdate = (from....where ....
                                  select l).Single();

         TheRecordToUpdate.TheDate = TheDate;
         TheRecordToUpdate.TheAction = TheAction;

         TheDC.SubmitChanges();
```

The problem is that sometimes I supply null parameters and when that's the case, I don't want to change the field in the DB. How do I use the ?? operator in linq-to-sql when the parameter is null?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `??` operator

```
TheRecordToUpdate.TheDate = TheDate ?? TheRecordToUpdate.TheDate ;
```

or if you want to write it more explicitly

```
if (TheDate.HasValue){
    TheRecordToUpdate.TheDate = TheDate;
}
```

if `TheRecordToUpdate.TheDate` is not a nullable property however, you'll have to write

```
if (TheDate.HasValue){
    TheRecordToUpdate.TheDate = TheDate.Value;
}
```

Comment: From me too. Clear intent in your own code instead of relying on an implicit behaviour of something downstream.

Comment: If they made a change to linq in terms of updating even if same, that could be a breaking change to your code (say if there was a timestamp in the record). Probably not likely in this case, but making your intent clear as a habit will save you all sorts of future problems.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the `??` operator like this:

```
TheRecordToUpdate.TheDate = TheDate ?? TheRecordToUpdate.TheDate;
```

It would update the field with the existing value, if `TheDate` is `null`. The code generated by the linq designer and SQL metal contains guards against assigning the same value, so this should not trigger an update of the database:

```
set
{
  if ((this._TheDate != value))
  {
    this.OnTheDateChanging(value);
    this.SendPropertyChanging();
    this._TheDate = value;
    this.SendPropertyChanged("TheDate");
    this.OnTheDateChanged();
  }
}
```

Anyways I think that using a normal `if` statement is more readable:

```
if (TheDate != null)
{
  TheRecordToUpdate.TheDate = TheDate;
}
```

As a side note, you're not following the normal casing conventions for variables. the `TheDate` parameter is usually written `theDate`.

Comment: I don't feel really comfortable with editing the auto-generated code but I know it's a possibility. Thanks for the answer; upvoted in case some want/need to go that route.

Comment: @frenchie: I don't mean that you should edit the auto-generated code, just wanted to show what it looks like to point out that linq-to-sql won't update the database when the same value is reassigned.

Answer (score 1):

The folowing trick should work.

```
TheRecordToUpdate.TheDate = TheDate ?? TheRecordToUpdate.TheDate;
TheRecordToUpdate.TheAction = TheAction ?? TheRecordToUpdate.TheAction;
```

If the parameters are null, then the values are updated but with the previous value, so it retains it's previous value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ternary to update to what it is now as per @sarwar026, personally I don't like it though, it relies on no change to the data being detected by the downstream functionality.
I'd just wrap it in `if TheDate.HasValue` etc. Can't see any value in being this clever.